# Neo4j lowest node java procedure

Tags: java, neo4j

I am creating procedure which could return lowest node in database but I have a problem. This code does not work for me. It will compile using Maven but then after start it will crash. 
Code is here:

```
@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;
@Procedure
@Description("Return lowest node")
public Stream<StringResult> get() {
    ResourceIterable<String> low = db.getAllPropertyKeys();
    List<String> node = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(low.iterator().hasNext()){
        String next = low.iterator().next();
        node.add(next);
    }
    String get = Collections.min(node);
    return Stream.of(new StringResult(Collections.min(node)));
    }

public class StringResult {
public final String value;

public StringResult(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

I will be thankfull if U will help me because I am really confused.

Comment: What do you mean with _"it will crash"_? What happens? Please be more specific.

Comment: Code look good and it will be compiled with status: Build success. But after adding into plugins directory and start of databe whole client will crash with Lyfecycle error.

Comment: Please add this to your question. There should be also a StackTrace. StackOverflow is not a debugging service